# UIAlertcontroller clears textview after pop up

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uialertcontroller

I have a uialertcontroller that I'm using when a user hits the 'Copy' button. The alert pops up, but I notice that behind the popup all of the text in the textview is cleared out. I'm not sure if this is normal behavior, but the copy function doesn't work because I'm wanting to grab the text from the textview which is no longer there.

I have tried changing the action buttons to print instead of copy to make sure the action buttons are working, and that part seems to work fine.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Copy", message: "How do you want to copy the text?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Full", style: .default, handler: {
            action in UIPasteboard.general.string = self.fullDecodedTextView.text
}))

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Partial", style:.default, handler: {
            action in UIPasteboard.general.string = self.fullDecodedTextView.text
            print("Does this even work?")

}))

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Cancel", style:.cancel, handler: nil))

self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

I'm expecting the popup to show and be able to copy the text in the UItextview. The text is disappearing as soon as the alert pops up though, and I believe that's why the copy isn't working.

Comment: no it's not normal, something in the code is clearing the text

Comment: It sounds like it is probably something in the code for the view controller with the text view. Could you post that here, so we could understand what is going on?

Comment: I'm still learning Swift, so which part of the code do you need? I'll be glad to post it. One thing I noticed while debugging was it appears after I hit the copy button, it jumps back to the IBOutlet UITextview. I'm wondering if it's getting reinitialized for some reason.

Comment: can you show us more of your code, where you init the text view, where you present this action sheet, also what else you do with this text field

Comment: check your viewDidAppear method, make sure you aren't resetting the textView.

Comment: I'm not using viewDidAppear explicitly. What do I need to check for?

Comment: Okay I found the issue, and all of you were right. I accidentally had my copy button set to an action for copy AND my clear button. Once I remove the link to the clear button everything started working.